# Can we return HashMap<String, Object> from jersey JSR-311 resource as response

Tags: java, jersey-1.0

I have a requirement of a response from jersey controller where name and type of the properties in response are returned from and external service and are not fixed, So I am thinking to return HashMap<String, Object>.
Can we return HashMap<String, Object> from jersey JSR-311 resource as response.
Or any other solution for it.

Sample Response looks like:

```
@XmlType
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
MyResponse{
@XmlElement
String id;

@XmlElement
HashMap<String, Object> properties;
}
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I tried with Map<String, Object> then I got exception 

javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: class com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap nor any of its super class is known to this context.
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap nor any of its super class is known to this context.]

Comment: One more thing I tried to use JsonObject of Gson but was getting field properties as null.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, any help will be appreciated..

Comment: Maps and JAXB don't work well together. If you are trying to use XML, you will need a custom adapter. If you are using JSON, you should try to use the Jackson provider instead of the default.